# Load page title from store in Nuxt.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am trying to load the page title after the store has been filled. However, I am not sure how to do it correctly.  This is how I understand it should be done, but it doesn't work. It says that the object isn't yet loaded (Cannot read property 'p_pdf_ad_headlines' of undefined).

How would I do this in Nuxt?

```
async fetch({ store, params }) {
    await store.dispatch('getMixedLanding', { id: params.id })
},
head() {
    return {
        title: this.$store.state.landing.p_pdf_ad_headlines.page_headline
            .text
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. For anyone else looking, the only thing I did was put the `dispatch` function in the `fetch` function. And the `head` stayed the same.

```
    async fetch({ store, params }) {
        const response = await axios.get(
            'http://example.com/item/' + params.id + '/'
        )
        store.commit('mixedResponse', response)
    },
```